# How to solve this fork() example in c

Tags: c, unix, process, operating-system, fork

```
int x=0;
int main()
{
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
    fork();
    x=x+5;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

[image: diagram]

I am a newbie to the `fork()` concept. Is the above tree (with `x` values) a correct solution for the C code mentioned above? The values in the nodes are the `x` values of their processes respectively.

And also can we return values to the parent process from the child process? Suppose in the above example code can I return the `x` value of the child to the parent process?

Comment: That won't even compile.

Comment: It's not quite clear what your graph means, but assuming (directed) edges represent parent-child process relationships and the root is the original process, then the 5 should be a 10 since each of the 4 processes ends up incrementing x by 5 twice. Anyway, what exactly is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: yes.The root in the diagram represents the starting original process and the directed edges shows the parent-child relationship.All I want to know is-In total how many nodes are formed and whether the x values in the respective nodes are correct or not?Thanks.

Comment: There is a distracting amount of whitespace in that graph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean that's a process tree and in the bubbles is the value of `x`? Then no, that's not correct.

When a child is spawned, it gets an exact copy of the parent... so let's "print" some values so we can see the state of things (I'm makeing up PIDs for everything)

When we start, it's just the parent:

```
parent (11174) x = 0, i = 0
```

Then we hit the `fork()`, now we have two processes:

```
 +--parent (11174) x = 0, i = 0
 |
 +->child1 (11175) x = 0, i = 0
```

Next the math:

```
 parent (11174) x = 5, i = 0

 child1 (11175) x = 5, i = 0
```

When we loop back up, our i's will be incremented, and each process now runs the loop and hits `fork()`:

```
 +--parent (11174) x = 5, i = 1
 |
 +->child2 (11176) x = 5, i = 1

 +--child1 (11175) x = 5, i = 1
 |
 +->child  (11177) x = 5, i = 1
```

Now everyone hits the math again:

```
 parent (11174) x = 10, i = 1

 child2 (11176) x = 10, i = 1

 child1 (11175) x = 10, i = 1

 child  (11177) x = 10, i = 1
```

Finally everyone hits the loop and increments `i` breaking from it. So your end result is:

```
 parent (10)----->child1(10)---->child(10)
           |
           +----->child2(10)
```

Comment: great explanation.Now I clearly understand how to solve these kinda problems.Thanks :)

Comment: @user1632141 - happy to help! It's useful to write down the steps so you can see it working, if you can't do it in your head then compile your small sample code and add some printfs, something like: `printf("process %d: x = %d, i = %d\n", getpid(), x, i);` would be a good place to start!

Answer (score 6):

If you call `fork()` then code below it is for both the processes i.e. `parent` and `child`.

`fork` creates a new process(known as child) whose address space is different than the parent process. So, nothing is shared between them.

You are calling fork in the loop , Actually 2 times , So there will be total 4 independent process.

If you want to do the separate coding in child process always use the returned value of the `fork()` like this :

```
if(!fork())
{
 // child process
}
else 
{
 // parent process
}
```

For questions this :

```
    And also can we return values to the parent process from the child process?
    Suppose lets say in the above example code can I return the x value of the 
    child to the parent process?
```

The answer is ,You can not return directly a value from one process to another .
The communication between 2 or more process is achieved using the concept called
Inter process commmunicaton (IPC) which you can done in 2 ways.

```
1. shared memory 
2. memssage passing (pipe, rpc)
```

Also there are lot many things you will have to understand before solving this problem.
Specially when you are trying to do it using `fork` and also want to return values

You should see [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-a-Process.html)

Or, this may help you [more](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/fork.html)

Comment: Anytime , but remember solving this one problem will not help you much, try to get the concept behind fork or any process creation and communication

Answer (score 2):

```
fork();
```

creates a child process and that copies all the variables of parent to the child variables.

**Parent:**

Your main program create 2 children as you mentioned in For-Loop,
when it creates `child1`, the value is `i` is `0`
when it creates `child2`, the value is `i` is `1`

**Child1:**

`Child1` start its execution after fork(), `i++` executed, in the next iteration(`i = 1`) - condition true (`1 < 2`), `Child1` forked another child  that is `child3`, in `child3` the value of `i` is `1`.

**Child2 and Child3:**

`Child2` and `Child3` start its execution with `i = 1` after fork(), `i++` executed, now `i` becomes `2`, condition false, no further child is created.

`3` processes created in Total.

**CODE:**

```
int x=0;
int main()
{
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
    fork();
    x=x+5;
  }
  printf("x = %d\n", x);
 return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
x = 10
x = 10
x = 10
x = 10
```